# Office 365 document Get a link View Edit URL using C# client object model

Tags: office-365, client-object-model, csom

I was trying to get the URL of a document (inside document library) link same as Get a Link option with View (account required).I am using following code with sharing options. SharingInfo object does not have such view link and it is more to sharing document with permission.

```
var sharingInfo = ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation(
clientContext, item, false, true, false, true, true, true, true);
clientContext.Load(sharingInfo);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

SharingInfo only provides anonymous links only

```
sharingInfo.AnonymousEditLink 
sharingInfo.AnonymousViewLink
```

What is the correct way to fetch Get a link Urls using c# client object mode .Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method available in Web (CSOM) to get share link.I have solved it by using this method

```
    public static ClientResult<string> CreateOrganizationSharingLink(
     ClientRuntimeContext context,
     string url,
     bool isEditLink
    )
```

Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.createorganizationsharinglink.aspx
for more details

Comment: Hello ,Can you please share little bit more on this .I have an exact requirement where i need to get the Edit link and View links for documents created

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GetWOPIFrameUrl` method to get that URL.

If you know the `Server Relative URL` of the file, you can use it as below:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/Shared Documents/abcd.docx");

var viewLink = file.ListItemAllFields.GetWOPIFrameUrl(SPWOPIFrameAction.View);

context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var value = viewLink.Value;
```

If you know the list item's ID or the list item object, you can use it as below:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents").GetItemById(1);

var viewLink = item.GetWOPIFrameUrl(SPWOPIFrameAction.View);

context.Load(item);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var value = viewLink.Value;
```

Reference - [ListItem.GetWOPIFrameUrl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.getwopiframeurl.aspx)

[SPWOPIAction enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spwopiaction.aspx)